# Javascript match everything betweet delimiters, including line breaks

Tags: javascript, regex

The following code correctly matches everything betweet `{{{` and `}}}` but the example 'line3' because the content of the brackets includes line breaks. How to match it as well?

```
const testcase = `
    line1: {{{ content1 }}}
    line2: {{{ content2 }}}
    line3: {{{
        content3
    }}}
    line4: {{{ content4 }}}
`;

const regex = /^(\s+)(.*?)(\{\{\{ [^]*? \}\}\})/gm;

let match;
while ( ( match = regex.exec(testcase) ) != null ) {
    console.log(match);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/^(\s+)(.*?)({{{[^]*?}}})/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qA8hT2/1)

Problem is presence of a space after `{{{` in your regex which is making it not match `line3` line since there is a line break after `{{{`.